German equivalents of "for that" and "for to"?
Despite searching, I have been unable to find any real equivalents for the above.
I have found some instances of "denn dass / denndass / denndaß", but this seems to be a very rare construction.
Are there any direct, stylistic equivalents which serve the functions as shown in the below examples?

For that there were few instances, it was difficult to find an equivalent.
I will for to find an equivalent.

Auf Deutsch geschrieben:

Denn dass﹖ es wenige Beispiele gab, war es schwer, ein Äquivalent zu finden.
Ich will für﹖ ein Äquivalent finden.

I will also note that these are no longer in common use; they are archaic constructions.
I have traced "for that" to Old English "forðæm, forðanðe"; being also an early West-Germanic language, I would imagine there is an equivalent in Old/Middle High German. "For that", in this sense, is used exclusively to indicate causality, but never consequentially (i.e. "for that it was so" but not "it was so; for that,").
"For to" was in use especially in Middle English, for instance: "What wolt thou me for to do?" "This behoueth me for to do".
Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe!

The first one, how is that different in meaning to because/since/as (= weil)? The second one I do not even understand in English, I have never seen this construction, so it would be helpful if you could add an explanation what it means.

What is "I will for to find an equivalent" supposed to mean?

@KilianFoth I believe it means sth along the lines of "...in order to..."

"for that" would neatly be expressed by "dafür", but honestly, I don't understand the English construct "for to". Could you edit your question, bringing another example of the use of "for to", in an appropritate context.

additionally, isn't it actually "Mesotherium"?

@Alazon: no, "Mesothorium" is correct. You see, there is Thorium, a chemical element, which can be very old ("Paläothorium") or very young ("Neothorium") but sometimes also of middle age, which is called Mesothorium.

for that
A dictionary entry for "for that" can be found here: en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_that. According to that, it means because / as / since / given that (German: weil / da / nachdem).

For that there were few instances, it was difficult to find an equivalent.
Da es nur wenige Beispiele gab, war es schwierig, eine Entsprechung zu finden.

"Dafür, dass..." would we very different, it has pretty much the opposite meaning, almost comparable to "in spite of". It means "considering that", like in

Considering that we're already in May, it is quite cold.
Dafür, dass schon Mai ist, ist es ziemlich kalt.

for to
Dictionary entry for "for to": oed.com/dictionary/for_prep?tab=meaning_and_use#3986755, so it seems to mean "in order to" (German "um zu"). "I will for to find an equivalent" seems to be an example that can lead to misunderstandings because it is missing a verb - what will you do for to find an equivalent? See RDBury's example "Coming for to carry me home", that has that extra verb. I don't think "will" can be that verb on its own.

I will work day and night for to find an equivalent.
Ich werde Tag und Nacht arbeiten, um eine Entsprechung zu finden.


You are looking for a da-adverb:

For that there were few …
Dafür, dass es einige …


I will for to find an equivalent.

Are you sure this is common in English? I never saw this before. Anyway, in German you can express it again with a da-Adverb and that is indeed common.

Ich finde dafür eine Entsprechung.


The combination "for to" is indeed rare in modern English. The refrain of the spiritual "Swing Low, Sweet Chariot" contains the line "Coming for to carry me home," but otherwise I'd consider it dialectical at best.

In "For that there were few..." there is the trivial "weil es wenige Beispiele.." To keep the rythm, there is the 2-word substitute "Denn weil es ... gab,.." and the somewhat archaic "Indeß es wenige....". The closest match is "Indem es wenige..." where "indem" is the compound of "in"+"dem". The "for to" is equivalent to "um zu" but requires to move the verb to the end of the German sentence.
